# how to write foreach in smarty?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, smarty

I am trying to use foreach in my application, with php it works fine.

```
foreach($allowed_menus as $key=>$value){
    $user_tabs[$value->TabOrder]['TabName'] = $value->TabName;
    $user_tabs[$value->TabOrder]['TabDesc'] = $value->TabName;
}
```

But I want to use in smarty templates which is .tpl files. and I wanna try the smarty foreach.

I have even tried this

```
{{foreach from=$allowed_menus key=k item=v}}
    {{/foreach}}
```

but it gives error.. internal server error.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl check this link you will get idea

Comment: @Reena
yes i have tried from there, this is why i am asking. cuz its not working...

Comment: Enable error reporting in your server so you can see what's going on instead of a internal server error screen. If you can't, follow the instructions of the post here: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php#85096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    {foreach $allowed_menus as $value}
      <a href="{$value.zig}">{$value.zag}</a>
      <a href="{$value.zig2}">{$value.zag2}</a>
      <a href="{$value.zig3}">{$value.zag3}</a>
    {foreachelse}
      There were no rows found.
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: thankyou, but why from dont work for me.. i mean in smarty site, they use from in foreach but you did wrote directly allowed_menus which worked for me.?

Answer (score 0):

Your are using double braces instead of single braces so change your code to something like this.

```
{foreach from=$allowed_menus key=k item=v}
  //foo
{/foreach}
```

Comment: actually i am using double braces in smarty.. it helps me distinct with javascript or jquery code in tpl files.
i dont want to write {literal} again and again.